# which one is more appropriate when talking about a near future? "at the end" or "by the end"

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I am learning this [course](https://youtu.be/4IAXaixaLWE?t=1)

> Hello everyone. Welcome to the second lecture for CS230. as I said
>   earlier, you can go to menti.com from your smartphones or your
>   computers and enter this code 84 5709 we will use this tool for
>   interactive questions during the lecture  and we will also use it to
>   track attendance. I'll add it at the end of the lecture, but if you
>   have time do it now.

The lecturer [is saying](https://youtu.be/4IAXaixaLWE?t=1)

> I'll add it at the end of the lecture.

this is a near future that is going to be happen.

in this context, "at the end" or "by the end", which one is more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two phrases imply different meanings:

> by the end

Implies that the action could take place any time during the lecture, and the addition process will definitely be complete when the lecture ends.

> at the end

Implies that the action will **not** take place during the beginning or middle or later-middle of the lecture. It means that the "addition" will take place right when the lecture is finishing or right after the lecture has finished.

**at the end** is probably the accurate choice because the lecturer will be lecturing during the lecture, as opposed to taking care of logistical problems.